# How to do map of two columns of different data frame and if get some null values then again mapping from other data frame and only fill null values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df1              df2               df3
t_cell t_psc     cell1  psc       cell2  psc2
fh4               dh2   2          fh4    5
dh2               jk2   3          ik5    7
jk2               po6   2          it7    9
ik5                                po6    3
po6
it7
```

output should be

```
t_cell t_psc
fh4     5
dh2     2
jk2     3
ik5     7
it7     9
po6     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with rename columnsnames in `df2` for same column like in `df3` with remove duplicates by `cell2` column:

```
s = (df2.rename(columns={'cell1':'cell2', 'psc':'psc2'})
        .append(df3)
        .drop_duplicates(['cell2'])
        .set_index('cell2')['psc2'])

df1['t_psc'] = df1['t_cell'].map(s)
print (df1)
  t_cell  t_psc
0    fh4      5
1    dh2      2
2    jk2      3
3    ik5      7
4    po6      2
5    it7      9
```

Another idea is use:

```
s1 = df1['t_cell'].map(df2.set_index('cell1')['psc'])
s2 = df1['t_cell'].map(df3.set_index('cell2')['psc2'])
df1['t_psc'] = s1.fillna(s2)
print (df1)
  t_cell  t_psc
0    fh4    5.0
1    dh2    2.0
2    jk2    3.0
3    ik5    7.0
4    po6    2.0
5    it7    9.0
```

Comment: not correct output

Comment: @RatiGoyal - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

First, rename your columns of `df2` and `df3` as `df1` then `concat` your 2 dataframes to create a dict mapping. Finally, map to the `t_cell` column:

```
df2.columns = ['t_cell', 't_psc']
df3.columns = ['t_cell', 't_psc']
df1['t_psc'] = df1['t_cell'].map(pd.concat([df2, df3]).set_index('t_cell')['t_psc'])
print(df1)

# Output
  t_cell  t_psc
0    fh4      5
1    dh2      2
2    jk2      3
3    ik5      7
4    po6      2
5    it7      9
```